# SP Online Export to Excel displays error

Tags: error, authentication, spo, export-to-excel

In On-Prem sites, Export to Excel is working fine.

But in SP Online sites, Export to Excel displays the below error:

"the server you are trying to access is using an authentication protocol not supported by this version of office"

I installed ActiveX controls and tired all fixes but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by following the below steps:

1. Open a blank Excel file, go to File  Account  Sign out  In the “Remove Account” pop-up window, Click “Yes” --> your account will be removed from Excel and now close the excel file.
2. Open any SharePoint Online site --> Lists --> Export to Excel. You may be getting a pop-up message saying “To export a list, you must have a Microsoft SharePoint foundation – compatible application”. Click Ok in this pop-up window.
3. You will get a notification to open/save “query.iqy” file. Click “open”
4. You will get a Excel Sign-in pop-up. Sign-in using your email Id and click “Next”.
5. Now SharePoint list data will be displayed in excel.